# Cloudflare Flexible SSL not working with vanilla Joomla site

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, joomla, cloudflare

I'm testing Flexible SSL on a newly installed Joomla site in preparation for the production site. However it doesn't seem to work.

Using default Joomla configuration: website loads, but content like CSS files and images are not loading, even though **all** the paths are relative. It's interesting to note that if I access the CSS files directly (with https) they show up fine.

If I configure Joomla for Force SSL, then the notorious redirect loop occurs.

What I've done so far:
- Set up Cloudflare page rule for http://mysub.domain.com/* to redirect to https, and making sure the subdomain mysub is routing through Cloudflare. This part is working, so the redirection works.

- Installed and enabled the Cloudflare Joomla plugin
- .htaccess file is NOT used in this case
- When Joomla's Force SSL is set to No, the Joomla constant JURI::root() returns http://mysub.domain.com, even though the site is accessed via https://mysub.domain.com. This means that internally, Joomla still views this as a http site. The only way to change this is to enable Force SSL, but that will result in the redirection loop.

I have searched everything, from Cloudflare's FAQ to Stackoverflow and Stackexchange, so I'm really out of ideas. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best if you contact support for this issue so we can help figure it out. We've seen a [similar issue with WordPress](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203487280--How-do-I-fix-the-infinite-redirect-loop-error-after-enabling-Flexible-SSL-with-WordPress-) that can be resolved by various plugins available in WordPress.

Someone also wrote something up on [redirect loops and fixing in .htaccess](https://gomah.fr/server-tips/forcing-https-redirection-and-cloudflares-flexible-ssl/) (don't know if this will help).

Comment: That link you provided worked like a charm (after a bit of tinkering). I've contacted cloudflare support yesterday, but since I'm a free user, I'm not holding my breath ;) I did discover a few quirks in my experimentation. Cloudflare SSL only works if Joomla's SEF is turned off. Maybe this can be useful to your engineers. I'll release a Joomla plugin for this soon :)

Comment: I've released a Joomla plugin for this issue, hope it'll help anyone else who comes across this question https://www.simbunch.com/products/free-extensions/cloudflare-for-joomla

Comment: Thanks! I'll put this in our knowledge base specific to Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, add the following code to your [.htaccess](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/.htaccess)

```
    #FileETag none
############################################
## FOR NGINX, LIGHTTPD, VARNISH OR ANY OTHER REVERSE PROXY TO APACHE
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```

Save.
You're done.
:D